# How to create a PHP process run consently

Tags: php, automation

I hope this is as clear as possible, it might be a little contradictory; however:

**I want to run PHP scripts all the time (automatically essentially)**

*I don't mean cron jobs*. To explain it better:

I have a separate PHP script which is carrying out tasks, and queuing actions in to a database. There could be several of these scripts running at once, adding to the que.

What I then want is a PHP script (or Application more like) to automatically say "OK, there is a new item qued, lets do it". Sometimes this que could be 4000 items long, other times it could be empty for a long period of time - therefore I don't foresee Cron jobs working, and calling it from the original file would cause long load times for the user executing the original script.

Is there another means of doing this? As cPanel is effectively a bunch of PHP files I thought there was likely a way.

Comment: It's called a "daemon", googling that would probably help you; but really you need a job server like gearman

Comment: side note, be careful its a great why to crash things, and you will need a VPS
 or better (not a shared host)

Comment: To add to @MarkBaker's comment you could also use [IronWorkers](https://www.iron.io/worker) as an alternative to Gearman. You can signup for the free account and see if you like it. [Pricing](https://www.iron.io/pricing#worker) and #idonotworkforIron